# How to divide a column into 5 groups by the column value sorted, and then add column's

Tags: python, pandas

How to divide an column into 5 groups by the column's value sorted.

and add a column by the groups

for example

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'x1':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]})
```

[image]

and I want add columns like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to look at [`pd.cut`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.cut.html), and set the argument `bins` to an integer of however many groups you want, and the `labels` argument to `False` (to return integer indicators of your groups instead of ranges):

```
df['add_col'] = pd.cut(df['x1'], bins=5, labels=False) + 1

>>> df
   x1  add_col
0   1        1
1   2        1
2   3        2
3   4        2
4   5        3
5   6        3
6   7        4
7   8        4
8   9        5
9  10        5
```

Note that the `+ 1` is only there so that your groups are numbered `1` to `5`, as in your desired output. If you don't say `+ 1` they will be numbered `0` to `4`

Comment: I have another problem, I wan't the number of the each group is the same,  (split by min 25% 50% 75% max).  Does **Numpy** have this method?

Comment: If you want it split by quantile, you can't guarantee that the numbers will be the same, but you can use `qcut` instead of `cut`: `pd.qcut(df['x1'], [0,0.25,0.5,0.75,1], labels=False)`